# How can I access the vertices of a mesh using the python API?

Tags: python

The vertex information I searched online using Python to obtain the model's vertex information is obj.data.vertices, but it is no longer available. I would like to ask where I can see the official API modifications after each version update of Blender

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

if obj and obj.type == 'MESH':
    vertices = obj.data.vertices

    for vertex in vertices:
        print(f"Vertex {vertex.index + 1}: {vertex.co}")

else:
    print("The current active object is not a grid model")
```

Comment: this code is perfectly fine. In which version are you using it?

Comment: Google search "Blender [version number] API changes"?.. You should find documentation... At the moment blender.org is being DDoS attacked, so it might not be possible to access temporarily.

Comment: I want to use it in Blender 3.6, but the method for obtaining model vertices in 3.6 doesn't seem to be vertices @lemon

Comment: Oh, no wonder I couldn't access Blender's official website and document webpage yesterday. @MartynasŽiemys

Comment: @MA__AM, it's still "vertices" (for every version I was able to be aware of).